# сайт с вопросами на одной странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

здравстуйте, хочу сделать сайт со следующими друг за другом вопросами, отвечаешь на один вопрос, на том же месте появляется другой, но без перехода на другую страницу, все должно быть в одном окошке, как пример сайт dualingo и чтобы сверху также была шкала от старта до финиша вопросов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так сначала сделайте, скиньте нам код, а мы вам поможем реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну, если в общем - можно так:

1. Накидать блоков с вопросами и вариантами ответов. Приделать конструкцию для прогресс-бара.
2. по умолчанию их не показывать. стилями.
3. Первому блоку по умолчанию добавить некий класс, который заставит браузер его показать.
4. По факту выбора варианта ответа убирать с блока этот класс и присобачивать его следующему по порядку блоку. Это скриптом.
5. Одновременно в прогресс-баре менять, скажем, ширину блока-индикатора, вычисляя ее пропорционально отношению числа пройденных вопросов к общему. Тем же скриптом.
6. Профит.

А если хотите, чтобы сделали все за вас - нет проблем, долларов за 50 можно =)